# ¿Cómo hago un INSERT de varios registros actualizando uno de ellos de acuerdo al registro anterior en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, insert, tsql, multiselect

En SQL Server tengo un INSERT a una tabla que funciona como historial.

Actualmente ya tengo la función de todo el INSERT salvo por un campo en específico:

```
INSERT INTO 
    BalanceTable
SELECT 
    MAX(a.SellerId) SellerId
    ,a.AgentId
    ,'Data registered' [Description]
    ,1 BalanceTypeId
    ,(SELECT SellerCom FROM AgentRate WHERE COUNT(at.AgentTransferId) BETWEEN NumberFrom AND NumberTo) Commission
    ,((SELECT TOP 1 Balance FROM BalanceTable ORDER BY 1 DESC) + (SELECT SellerCom FROM AgentRate WHERE COUNT(at.AgentTransferId) BETWEEN NumberFrom AND NumberTo)) Balance
    ,GETDATE() EnteredDate
FROM 
    Agent a
INNER JOIN
    AgentTransfer at ON (at.AgentId = a.AgentId) 
WHERE 
    DAY(at.AgentTransferDate) = DAY(@Date) 
    AND MONTH(at.AgentTransferDate) = MONTH(@Date)
    AND at.AgentTransferTypeId = 1
GROUP BY 
    a.AgentId
```

Mi problema es que la columna "Balance" debería regresar el último registro por cada nuevo registro que vaya a guardar, para que conforme añada una fila nueva, obtenga la anterior y sume el valor con el nuevo y de esa forma vaya actualizándolo.

Por todo lo demás, la consulta funciona bien, solo es este dato, que vuelvo a repetir: Debe regresar el anterior dato guardado, para sumarlo con el nuevo dato a ingresar.

Un saludo y gracias :)

Comment: Para contestar esta pregunta, necesitas incluir la estructura de las tablas, datos de prueba y los resultados basados en esos datos de prueba. Todo esto en código SQL para no perder tiempo en generarlo nosotros.